# Is it correct to combine a singular and plural form of a word this way?

Tags: plural-forms, singular

I have a question. Is it correct to combine a singular and plural form of a word this way?

> For this purpose, the Manager should agree with the security officers **(a) codeword(s)**.

My problem is that the indefinite article is in the parentheses simultaneously with the "s", so I would read this as "Codeword" or "A codewords".
I couldn't find examples of the same construction on the Internet but I often see it in documents of the company I work in.

Comment: *...the Manager should agree **the codeword(s)** with **the security officer(s)**.* If it's known that there are multiple "codewords" and/or "security officers", you'd write those as plurals and not include preceding article ***the*** (you can't include the *indefinite* article ***a*** unless there's definitely only one of whatever follows).

Comment: I would word it: *the Manager should agree with the security officers **on the codeword(s)** in use.*

Comment: It's a mistake.

Comment: I would interpret it as meaning 'one or more codewords, depending on how many are needed' - to be read as **a codeword** or **codewords**, as appropriate.